# Comparing Files based on 5 fields using Awk and Bash

Tags: bash, awk

I want to compare File1 and File2 (Separated by spaces) using five fields (Column 1,2,4,5,6).

**Logic:**If column 1 and 2 of File1 and File2 match exactly and if the File2 has the same characters as any of the characters present in column 4 and 5 of file1 then those lines of file1 and file2 are concatenated and redirected as output.

**File1:**

```
s2/80   20      .       A       T       86      N=2     F=5;U=4
s2/20   10      .       G       T       90      N=2     F=5;U=4
s2/90   60      .       C       G       30      N=2     F=5;U=4
```

**File2:**

```
s2/90   60      .       G       G       97      N=2     F=5;U=4
s2/80   20      .       A       A       20      N=2     F=5;U=4
s2/15   11      .       A       A       22      N=2     F=5;U=4
s2/90   21      .       C       C       82      N=2     F=5;U=4
s2/20   10      .       G       G       99      N=2     F=5;U=4
s2/80   10      .       T       G       11      N=2     F=5;U=4
s2/90   60      .       G       T       55      N=2     F=5;U=4
```

**Output:**

```
s2/80  20 . A   T   86  N=2 F=5;U=4  s2/80  20  . A   A   20   N=2     F=5;U=4
s2/20  10 . G   T   90  N=2 F=5;U=4  s2/20  10  . G   G   99   N=2     F=5;U=4
s2/90  60 . C   G   30  N=2 F=5;U=4  s2/90  60  . G   G   97   N=2     F=5;U=4
```

I'm new in this field and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: About how many lines are you talking? Are both files the same size or is one rather small?

Comment: Can fields 4 and 5 be more than one character long? Do you mean that you want to check whether the set intersection of `{file1:fields 4,5}` and `{file2:fields 4,5}` is not empty? Why do you mention field 6, since it doesn't seem to fit into your matching algorithm? Do you care about the order of the lines in the output? (Writing a precise problem description is the first step to writing a program.)

Comment: Is there a typo in your 3rd line of your sample output? The bit from the 2nd file shows "G T", but your sample output shows "G G".

Comment: @ott: No both files do not have the same number of lines.

Comment: @slm : No, in the output file there is no typo. The File 2 has s2/90   60      .       G       G       97      N=2     F=5;U=4 and s2/90   60      .       G       T       55      N=2     F=5;U=4. But the output file should have the one before "G G" because the Logic is if column 1 and 2 matches exactly then it goes to column 4 and 5. If column 4 and 5 of file 1 has "X Y" then from file2 it should only capture those with "X X" or "Y Y".

Comment: The columns 4 and 5 reminds me of DNA. Shouldn't they be only A-T, T-A, C-G and G-C only?

Comment: @ott-- You are right. They are DNA nucleotides. They can be of any sequence. But for my analysis, I am only looking for particular ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using just `awk`. Put the below code in a file called `ex.awk`:

```
BEGIN{}
FNR==NR{
    k=$1" "$2
    a[k]=$4" "$5
    b[k]=$0
    c[k]=$4
    d[k]=$5
    next
}

{ k=$1" "$2
  lc=c[k]
  ld=d[k]
  # file1 file2
  if ((k in a) && ($4==$5) && (lc==$4) || (ld==$5)) print b[k]" "$0
}
```

And then run it like this with the above 2 files:

```
$ awk -f ex.awk file1 file2
```

#### Example

The `sed` is just to format the output for StackExchange!

```
$ awk -f ex.awk file1 file2 | sed 's/[ ]\+/  /g'
s2/90  60  .  C  G  30  N=2  F=5;U=4  s2/90  60  .  G  G  97  N=2  F=5;U=4
s2/80  20  .  A  T  86  N=2  F=5;U=4  s2/80  20  .  A  A  20  N=2  F=5;U=4
s2/20  10  .  G  T  90  N=2  F=5;U=4  s2/20  10  .  G  G  99  N=2  F=5;U=4
```

#### A change in requirements

The OP mentioned in the comments below that he'd like the ultimate solution to drop any lines where the 4th and 5th columns from `file1` matched the 4th and 5th columns from `file2`.

For example, add this line to both `file1` & `file2`:

```
s2/40   40      .       S       S       90      N=2     F=5;U=4
```

A single line addition to the original solution can address this particular change in the requirements.

```
if ((k in a) && (lc==$4) && (ld==$5)) next
```

#### New Example

`ex2.awk`:

```
BEGIN{}
FNR==NR{
  k=$1" "$2
  a[k]=$4" "$5
  b[k]=$0
  c[k]=$4
  d[k]=$5
  next
}

{ k=$1" "$2
  lc=c[k]
  ld=d[k]
  if ((k in a) && (lc==$4) && (ld==$5)) next
  if ((k in a) && ($4==$5) && (lc==$4) || (ld==$5)) print b[k]" "$0
}
```

Rerunning the new `awk` script, `ex2.awk`:

```
$ awk -f ex2.awk file1 file2 | sed 's/[ ]\+/  /g'
s2/90  60  .  C  G  30  N=2  F=5;U=4  s2/90  60  .  G  G  97  N=2  F=5;U=4
s2/80  20  .  A  T  86  N=2  F=5;U=4  s2/80  20  .  A  A  20  N=2  F=5;U=4
s2/20  10  .  G  T  90  N=2  F=5;U=4  s2/20  10  .  G  G  99  N=2  F=5;U=4
```

Comment: Hi slm, Thanks for your quick answer. But my last line should be s2/90  60 . C   G   30  N=2 F=5;U=4  s2/90  60  . G   G   97   N=2     F=5;U=4. Logic: Column 1 and Column 2 of file 1 and 2 should exactly match and if column 4 and 5 of File 1 has "X Y"
then it should look for either "X X" or "Y Y" in file 2. No other combination.

Comment: It works perfect. Thanks Slm. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Namrata - this code doesn't work if you have more than one match in file1, BTW. So if you have 2 "s2/90   60" the 2nd one will be the one that's used. That's a limitation of your algorithm. You probably know this but just letting you know.

Comment: I found out, if there is an overlap between the File1 and File2 it also printing that as output. I added another line "s2/40  40  .  S  S  90  N=2  F=5;U=4" to both File1 and File2 and I get this line concatenated in the output. But I do not want to have this kind of intersection in my output file.

Comment: Can you please help me getting the correct output file.

Comment: @Namrata - I added the line you mentioned to both file1 and file2 and it shows up. As the algorithm stands it's doing what it's suppose to. How would you like to change it so that doesn't do this? What additional logic needs to be added to your algorithm? If the line in file1 is identical, don't display it?

Comment: Yes. If in file1 we have A T and file2 also has A T then it should not display it.

Comment: @Namrata - see updates.