# Looking for lines which is in one file but not in other using Unix and Awk

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

I have 2 files with 7 fields and I want to print the lines which are present in file1 but not in file2 based on field1 and field2.

Logic: I want to print all the lines, where there is a particular column1 and column2. And we do not find the set of column1 and column2 in file2. Example: "sc2/10    10" this set you would not see in file 2, therefore it is printed as output.

File1:

```
sc2/80         20      .        A       T         86       F=5;U=4
sc2/60         55      .        G       T         76       F=5;U=4
sc2/10         10      .        G       C         50       F=5;U=4
sc2/68         20      .        T       C         71       F=5;U=4
sc2/24         24      .        T       G         31       F=5;U=4
sc2/11         30      .        A       T         60       F=5;U=4
```

File2:

```
sc2/80         20      .        A       T         30       F=5;U=4 
sc2/60         55      .        T       T         77       F=5;U=4 
sc2/68         20      .        C       C         01       F=5;U=4
sc2/24         29      .        T       G         31       F=5;U=4
sc2/24         19      .        G       G         11       F=5;U=4
sc2/88         89      .        T       G         51       F=5;U=4
```

Expected Output:

```
sc2/10         10      .        G       C         50       F=5;U=4 
sc2/11         30      .        A       T         60       F=5;U=4
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86590/comparing-files-based-on-5-fields-using-awk-and-bash

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless the input is huge, I would go with saving the `file2` pairs into a hash and use it to ignore lines in `file1`. For example:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { h[$1,$2]; next }; !($1 SUBSEP $2 in h)' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
sc2/10         10      .        G       C         50       F=5;U=4         
sc2/24         24      .        T       G         31       F=5;U=4
sc2/11         30      .        A       T         60       F=5;U=4
```

IIUC `sc2/24 24` is correctly included in the output.

#### Explanation

- `FNR == NR { h[$1,$2]; next }` saves `$1/$2` pairs into the `h` hash (note that accessing an array by subscript is enough to allocate it), but only from the first input file (`file2`). The `next` command skips to the next record.
- `! ($1 SUBSEP $2 in h)` is only evaluated for `file1` and will invoke the default block for lines *not* containing the `$1/$2` pairs. The default block is `{ print $0 }`. (note: avoid using `!h[$1,$2]` (same as `!h[$1 SUBSEP $2]`) as that would allocate it)

The above assumes the value of `SUBSEP` (usually the `^\` character) is not found in the first two fields of the file.

Answer (score 0):

**`grep -Fvxf <remove> <all-lines>`**

- works on non-sorted files
- maintains the order
- [is POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)

Example:

```
cat <<EOF > A
b
1
a
0
01
b
1
EOF

cat <<EOF > B
0
1
EOF

grep -Fvxf B A
```

Output:

```
b
a
01
b
```

Explanation:

- `-F`: use literal strings instead of the default BRE
- `-x`: only consider matches that match the entire line
- `-v`: print non-matching
- `-f file`: take patterns from the given file

This method is slower on pre-sorted files than other methods, since it is more general. If speed matters as well, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204904/fast-way-of-finding-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another